Is there some kind of property guard in typescript?
I'm aware of type guards but i'd like to use what i would have called a property guard - however i couldn't find something like it in the documentation.
What i have in mind is this
const LenGtZero = (e: RequireLength) => 0 < e.length;

Where type RequireLength is supposed to enforce having the property length.
I thougt of an abstract or normal class but didn't know how to force the following predicate to the constructor
hasLength<T extends object>(obj: T): obj is T  {
  return obj.hasOwnProperty("length")
}

I don't even know if generics are necessary here. I found here some threads about narrowing and inferring type but i guess i'm too unfamiliar with typescript - i didn't understand them.
Also an interface or a type were acceptable - but what i didn't want is the construction of an union or intersection type.
I wonder if i have to make use of keyof or the any or unknown types but at this point i little worn out and would be grateful for some help with this.

You can use const LenGtZero = (e: { length: number }) => 0 < e.length;.

I think you can typeGuard it using this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in (the 'in' operator can act as a typeGuard, you propbably have to make a function to make it work)

It's the best solution so far. But this looks like an anonym type to me and seems therefore not a good practice in regards of reuse purposes.

? Do you mean “anonymous”? Feel free to name that type and use its name, then. I’ll show you when I get to a real computer.

Look at this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so someone can write an answer or link a suitable duplication source; if not, what's missing?

The intention is what i would call a property guard. This solution of yours wouldn't allow me to pass any object which has the property 'length'. See this altered example: playground ...and yes 'anonymous', thx :)

Please [edit] the question to show the required use cases, such as SomethingElse. Since SomethingElse doesn't necessarily have a length, then you're trying to possibly compare 0 < undefined, but TS considers that an error. If you want to allow "a length which is either a number or missing/undefined" then we could change your code to this version and it starts working. Does that meet your needs now? If not, what's missing now?

You can actually narrow with the in-operator. To check if an object has a property length all you have to do is the following:
if("length" in obj) ...

or as a user defined type guard with a type predicate:
function hasLength(obj: object): obj is { length: number } {
  return "length" in obj;
}


For example:
declare const toNarrow: { foo: string; length: number } | { bar: string };

if (hasLength(toNarrow)) {
  toNarrow;
  //^? const toNarrow: { foo: string; length: number; }
}

TypeScript Playground

You provide a function solution. The function used in the question already works. What i'm searching for is a way to use is 'automatically' in some kind of type.
